# PHPQuery -> WebBrowser Example 2 won't work [still looking for answer]

Tags: browser, phpquery

I can't seem to get this code working

```
phpQuery::$ajaxAllowedHosts = 'google.com'; 
phpQuery::browserGet('http://www.google.com/', 'success1');
function success1($browser) {
  $browser
    ->WebBrowser('success2')
    ->find('input[name=q]')
      ->val('search phrase')
      ->parents('form')
        ->submit();
}
function success2($browser) {
  print $browser;
}
```

It's example 2 from this page:http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/WebBrowser

All it does is just output blank.

Can someone see anything I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: FYI tried changing google.com.au to www.google.com.au in allowed host and no difference.

Comment: changed the question from google.com.au to google.com (for allowed hosts). Still no fix

Answer (score 0):

You've allowed the `google.com.au` host then made a request to a different host `google.com`.

Comment: Thanks that's a good point. Corrected that and still no fix. Any other ideas/